# Two plane curves that are Bertrand mates are the same curve iff they are parametrized by the arc length.

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Suppose $\alpha(s)$ and $\beta(s)$ are two plane curves with non-zero curvatures.
I want to show that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are Bertrand mates (two curves are called Bertrand mates if they have the same normal lines at each parameter), then $\alpha(s)=\beta(s)$ for each $s$, in other words $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the same curve iff $s$ is the arclength parameter.

My progress:

First I’m gonna assume $s$ is the arclength parameter. So we get $\alpha’’(s)\perp \alpha’(s)$ and similarly $\beta’’(s)\perp\beta’(s)$. So the parametric equation of the normal lines to $\alpha(s)$ and $\beta(s)$ at each $s$ (denoted by $L_{\alpha}(t)$ and $L_{\beta}(t)$ respectively) are:

$L_{\alpha}(t)=t\alpha’’(s)+\alpha(s)$

$L_{\beta}(t)=t\beta’’(s)+\beta(s)$

Since the normal lines are the same at each $s$ we get:

$\forall s\,\forall t: t\alpha’’(s)+\alpha(s)= t\beta’’(s)+\beta(s)$

Or equivalently:

$\forall s\,\forall t: t(\alpha’’(s)-\beta’’(s))= \beta(s)-\alpha(s)$

Now if $\alpha\neq\beta$, then there exists an $s_0$ such that $\alpha(s_0)\neq\beta(s_0)$ implying $\|\beta(s_0)-\alpha(s_0)\|\neq 0$.

So we have:

$\forall t: t(\alpha’’(s_0)-\beta’’(s_0))= \beta(s_0)-\alpha(s_0)$

Implying:

$\forall t: |t|\|\alpha’’(s_0)-\beta’’(s_0)\|= \|\beta(s_0)-\alpha(s_0)\|$

Dividing both sides by the non-zero $\|\beta(s_0)-\alpha(s_0)\|$ and then by $|t|$ (assuming $t\neq0$) yields:

$\underbrace{\dfrac{\|\alpha’’(s_0)-\beta’’(s_0)\|}{\|\beta(s_0)-\alpha(s_0)\|}}_{\text{constant}}=\dfrac1{|t|}\quad\forall t\neq 0$

which is contradiction.

What’s wrong with my proof?

I kinda didn’t use the fact that both curves are parametrized by the arc length.

$\mathbf{Update}:$

I was wrong since for each $s$, the two normal lines need not have the same point for each parameter $t$ as Prof. Shifrin Stated. So I updated my progress.

Since the two curves are Bertrand mates we conclude that:

$\beta(s)=\alpha(s)+\lambda\mathbf{N}_{\alpha}(s)$

So the distance between the points $\alpha(s)$ and $\beta(s)$ is constant:

$\|\alpha(s)-\beta(s)\|=\lambda$

Now we have to prove $\lambda=0$

Let’s assume to the contrary that $\lambda\neq0$. Differentiating both sides yields:

$\dfrac{\langle\alpha’(s)-\beta’(s),\alpha(s)-\beta(s)\rangle}{\|\alpha(s)-\beta(s)\|}=0$

So we get:

$\|\alpha’(s)-\beta’(s)\|=0 \Longrightarrow \alpha’(s)=\beta’(s)\quad\forall s$

How can I go further?

Comment: Without the arclength parametrization, why is $\beta’’$ the normal?

Comment: If the curves aren’t parametrized by the arclength, then the equations of the normal lines would be:

$L_{\alpha}(t)=t\mathbf{N}_{\alpha}(s)+\alpha(s)$

$L_{\beta}(t)=t\mathbf{N}_{\beta}(s)+\beta(s)$ and with similar process, we conclude that $\alpha=\beta$. So what’s so special about the fact that both curves have arclength parameter? 
So what’s wrong with my proof? 
Also, how can I prove the converse? If $\alpha=\beta$ then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are obviously Bertrand mates and they need not be parametrized by the arclength.

Comment: I would like to see the precise statement of the exercise. My guess is that we're starting with an arclength-parametrized curve $\alpha(s)$, defining $\beta(s)=\alpha(s)+r(s)\mathbf N_\alpha(s)$, and then analyzing when $\beta$ is a Bertrand mate and seeing when $\beta$ has speed $1$.

Comment: I was given this question as an exercise but I don’t know the original source of it. Let $\alpha(s)$ and $\beta(s)$ be two regular plane curves with non-zero curvatures. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are Bertrand mates then prove that $s$ is the arclength parameter for both curves if and only if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the same curve. Also note that the original question was not in English so I had to translate it.

Comment: Well, I suggest you proceed as I outlined it … Your proof is flawed from the beginning. No one says the parameters for the normal lines end up identical.

Comment: Right! I updated my progress but I don’t know how to proceed.

Comment: How did you get $\|\alpha’-\beta’\|=0$? As I suggested, compute the speed of $\beta$. How can it be $1$?

Comment: So I arrived at the following conclusion:

Since the normals to $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are parallel at each $s$, we conclude that $\alpha’$ and $\beta’$ are also parallel at each $s$. Moreover, since $\|\alpha’\|=\|\beta’\|=1$ at each $s$, we conclude that $\alpha’=\pm\beta’$. Now I just have to show that $\alpha’=\beta’$. Assuming $\alpha’=\beta’$, I get $\beta’=\alpha’+\lambda\alpha’’’$ from the last equation and therefore $\lambda\alpha’’’=0$ yielding $\lambda=0$. Is this correct?

Comment: I don't know why you are refusing to use the Frenet equations from the outset. Rather than writing $\alpha'''$ (what is that?), just go back to the beginning and find $\beta'$ in terms of the Frenet frame of $\alpha$.